# How to make a fixed header scroll horizontal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header div with following css properties:

```
.header{
 top: 0px;width: 100%;min-width: 980px;
 height: 70px;position: fixed;
}
```

The problem here is when I zoom into browser the header navigation links on the right are thrown out of page. So I want to have a fixed header that scrolls horizontally along with the rest of the page on zooming browser. Went through some of javascript answers to related questions but none is promising.

Comment: can you provide  jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `min-width` and the `width` properties because I'm assuming that you want the full width of the window. All you would need to use is the `top` `left` and `right` equalled to the value of `0`. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h4dyex8z/)

```
.header{
 margin: 0;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 70px;position: fixed;
 background-color: white;
}
a {
  float: right;
}
```